# Angular 4 can't ng build get 'ERROR in multi script-loader'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

When I try to run `sudo ng build --prod --env=prod --aot=false`, the build stops at `92% chunk asset optimization` and I get following error message:

```
ERROR in multi script-loader!./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js script-loader!./node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' in '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
resolve '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' in '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
  using description file: /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    using description file: /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js doesn't exist
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js]
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js.ts]
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js.js]
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js]
 @ multi script-loader!./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js script-loader!./node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js
ERROR in multi script-loader!./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js script-loader!./node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js' in '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
resolve '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js' in '/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
  using description file: /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    using description file: /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        /home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js doesn't exist
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js]
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js.ts]
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js.js]
[/home/ubuntu/teller-install/App/teller-app/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js]
 @ multi script-loader!./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js script-loader!./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js script-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js script-loader!./node_modules
```

/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js

Does anyone know why this is happening? I can build everything just fine in the dev environment but this error only happens on the production environment.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have a discrepancy in your `package.json`'s dependencies and you are not including one of the required scripts?

Comment: Can you show the angular-cli.json file? So you should be tried to re-install npm packages too.